# What's should I call a Location (Longitude and Latitude) associated with a DateTimeOffset?

Tags: c#, naming, semantics, xamarin

In the `Xamarin.Essentials` library there is a `Location` class that comes with a `DateTimeOffset` `TimeStamp`.

I know I'm being pedantic and I should just move on - I know it's to indicate a location *of the device* at a *moment in time*, but I don't like this.  Locations in three-dimensional space have no associated concept of time.

What would be a better description (and class name) for "a device location at a given instant in time"? `TemporalLocation`? `LocationInstant`?

Comment: According to my tardis manual, the term you’re looking for is space-time coordinates. Might be a little wordy for your needs. Try reversing the polarity of the neutron flow.

Comment: Depends who your "target audience" is. To a mathematician, the term "location" could be perfectly acceptable, because in the abstract, there's no real difference between (x, y, z) and (x, y, z, t), or (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5), etc. All of those are points in an n-dimensional space, and if you label one axis as "time", it doesn't make a difference. In physics, general relativity makes use of spacetime coordinates (3D location + time coordinate); in their lingo, a point in that space is called an *event*; that's a fairly good name, but in the software world that term is pretty overloaded already.

Comment: I'm quite wary of jargon-ish words unless they form part of the widely-accepted domain vocabulary.    Otherwise, a short and simple "plain English" phrase is often the best way to communicate and preserve intent, readability and clarity for your audience (other developers) because it makes the least assumptions about their vocabulary.  If you need to use phrase-names such as `LocationAtTime`, then this is more likely to convey the right intent to a reader without confusing them than trying to find "clever" words in dark corners of the dictionary.

Comment: “Presence” might work as the name for something that combines a position with a timestamp. Location works but does have more of a position-only connotation.

Comment: `SpaceTimeComposite`

Answer (score 3):

It is quite common to name a class according to it's main functionality, and not trying to express any available meta data property through the name as well.

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.location?view=xamarin-essentials), `Location` objects do not only provide a time stamp, they also have things like an accuracy, a vertical accuracy, an altitude reference system or a speed value. This can be seen as  accompanying information to the main functionality (which is providing a latitude, longitude and altitude measured by a gps sensor).

> Locations in three-dimensional space have no associated concept of time.

For **measured** data it is pretty common to include the concept of a time stamp. So IMHO the name `Location` fits well in the context of  Xamarin.Essentials, you may just have to change your point of view a little bit and don't try to interpret the objects as "timed locations", but simply as locations with additional meta data.

Note this class is obviously not optimized for memory space, it is optimized for providing a mostly self-contained piece of data from a sensor. I don't know the full Xamarin API, but a short look into the docs gave me the impression does not provide a data type for "pure coordinate" data, without any metadata, so this is simply not the kind of requirement or use cases that API aims for.  If one needs to store or process millions of locations (for example, from a LIDAR scan), then one should probably provide a more specific class, holding exactly the properties required (which may or may not include a time stamp or other properties).

Answer (score 0):

As others warn, in software I'd avoid the generalisations from maths and physics.

You could call a time and place an `appointment`, which unfortunately has an enormously strong connotation of pre-planned events concerning people, but otherwise the English language seems to make a clear conceptual distinction between time and place, with no single word for a unit of information conveying both a time and a place.

This is probably because specific times and places are themselves rarely condensed into one atomic word, or expressed in equivalent terms such as with coordinates, instead they are often expressed as dates and place names which are irreconcilable specifications.

The only technical term I can find which might for the bill is `chronotope`, which is apparently a Russian coinage first applied to analysis of literature, but comes from Greek stems meaning literally "time" and "space".

Answer (score 0):

`LocationEvent`

An event indicates a single time component. This could be expressed as an absolute time or an offset.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there can be a single answer to your question, because in my opinion the best name for a unit of data depends on what use you plan to make of it. That is, if the time is in the future, it may represent a planned location for some object, or if the time is in the past, it could represent a reading from a device, which may in-turn be one of several such measurement devices from which your algorithm might be selecting data to use in navigation.  Or the past locations could simply be an expired plan which has not been followed by any object whatsoever!
If it helps, you could think of this as a four-dimensional location rather than a three-dimensional location. It just so happens that you are simply ignoring one of the dimensions, which is perfectly fine. One other suggestion: I suggest not leaving the value of the timestamp undefined.  That is, you assign new instances a value which represents "not applicable", "undefined", "not assigned", so you don't end up with code which says the coordinate has a time stamp of January 1, 1970, for example.